# Ember.js setupController fired only once

Tags: javascript, ember.js, javascript-framework

Suppose I have a view:

```
CellarRails.SearchTextField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  templatename: 'index',
  insertNewline: function(){
    this.get('controller').set('query', this.get('value'));

    // calling search method of application controller
    this.get('controller').send('search');
    this.set('value', '');
  }
});
```

And an `applicationController`:

```
CellarRails.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['search'],
  query: '',

  // here is the search method
  search: function() {

    // I'm using ember-query lib, which provides this helper, it acts just like usual transitionToRoute
    this.transitionToRouteWithParams('search', {
      q: this.get('computedQuery')
    });
  },
  computedQuery: function() {
    this.get('controllers.search').set('q', this.get('query'));
    return this.get('query');
  }.property('query')
});
```

So now it should be transitioned to `searchRoute`:

```
CellarRails.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  serializeParams: function(controller) {
    return {
      q: controller.get('q')
    };
  },
  deserializeParams: function(params, controller) {
    controller.set('q', params.q);
  },

  // pass CellarRails.Track model to SearchController's context
  setupController: function(controller, context, params) {
    console.log('setup controller hooked!');
    controller.set('context', CellarRails.Track.find(params));
  }
});
```

In the `CellarRails.Track` model I have redefined a `find` method.
**PROBLEM:** This code works, but `setupController` hook fires only for the first time (when I transition from `applicationRoute` to `searchRoute`), **BUT** if I already in `searchRoute` this hook doesn't fire and `find` method of `CellarRails.Track` model doesn't fire too.

Answer (score 3):

When you setup `setupController` on your route the `model` hook is not invoked. If you want that both hooks `model` and `setupController` should fire you have to call `this._super(...)` in your `setupController` hook to maintain the `model` hook default behaviour:

```
CellarRails.SearchRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  ...
  model: function(params) {
    return CellarRails.MyModel.find();
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    this._super(controller, model);
    ...
  }
  ...
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Looks like thing I could work with, thank you, but is it okay to do things like that? I mean it looks hacky a bit, isn't it?

Comment: @Nikita, I know it might look hacky, but that exact behaviuor was introduced since RC4: http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/05/28/ember-1-0-rc4.html so you are fine at doing it :)

Comment: the problem is still there - it works if I transition from `applicationRoute` to `SearchRoute`, but if I'm already on `searchRoute` and execute `didInsertElement` of `SearchTextField`, which fires `search` method of `applicationController`, which should fire `transitionToRoute` to `SearchRoute` - it doesn't happen, `setupController` hook doesn't fire twice.

Comment: I think I made a logical mistake somewhere in design.

Comment: @Nikita, hmm, looking at your code it looks like you are using the `ember-query` lib, it might be related to the behaviour you are experiencing

Comment: Maybe and maybe not, I think `ember-query` should not affect on how `model` and `setupController` hooks should fired.

Comment: yep, you were right, model hook doesnt fire only if I use ember-query lib.

Answer (score 0):

try using the model: hook in the SearchRoute

```
model: function ( params, transition ) {
    return CellarRails.Track.find(params);
}
```

This gets called if you navigate direct to the url, hopefully the required params will be in the params but try doing a debug on it to check :)

Comment: ` If the route is entered through a transition (e.g. when using the linkTo Handlebars helper), then a model context is already provided and this hook is not called.`

Comment: In my case route entered through a transition. Anyway model hook fired only once too.

Comment: Are you wanting to move from the searchroute to the searchroute is that what you mean? In this case I would consider using the {{ action }} helper to control what the button does instead of a linkTo

Comment: I don't use buttons or linkTo helpers in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an explanation of this issue:
https://github.com/alexspeller/ember-query/issues/9